# Pygame event types by Joysticks

Tags: python, pygame, controller

I'm using a PS5 Dualsense controller with my computer to make a simple macro keyboard, and I used a tutorial where JOYHATMOTION and JOYBALLMOTION were used. I have been experimenting with my controller, and I can't seem to find what JOYHATMOTION and JOYBALLMOTION are used for. I was wondering if anyone used the event types and knew further about this.

Comment: [What Is a Hat Switch on a Joystick?](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-a-hat-switch-on-a-joystick)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what both `JOYHATMOTION` and `JOYBALLMOTION` are, but from my reading from the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) it seems to me that the `pygame.joystick.Joystick()` function returns 5 events `JOYAXISMOTION JOYBALLMOTION JOYBUTTONDOWN JOYBUTTONUP JOYHATMOTION` including `JOYBALLMOTION AND JOYHATMOTION` which i can guess are movement values generated when moving the hat of the joystick, read more about it in the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html)